# Visualising logistic regression using the effects package in R

Tags: r, visualization, logistic-regression, effects

I am using the [effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) package in R to plot the effects of categorical and numerical predictors in a binomial logistic regression estimated using the lme4 package. My dependent variable is the presence or absence of a virus in an individual animal and my predictive factors are various individual traits (eg. sex, age, month/year captured, presence of parasites, scaled mass index (SMI), with site as a random variable).

When I use the `allEffects` function on my regression, I get the plots below. When compared to the model summary output below, you can see that the slope of each line appears to be zero, regardless of the estimated coefficients, and there is something strange going on with the scale of the y-axes where the ticks and tick labels appear to be overwritten on the same point.

[image]

Here is my code for the model and the summary output:

```
library(lme4)
library(effects)
virus1.mod<-glmer(virus1~ age + sex + month.yr + parasites + SMI + (1|site) , data=virus1data, family=binomial)
virus1.effects<-allEffects(virus1.mod)
plot(virus1.effects, ylab="Probability(infected)", rug=FALSE)  

> summary(virus1.mod)
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
     Family: binomial ( logit )
    Formula: virus1 ~ age + sex + month.yr + parasite + SMI + (1 | site)
       Data: virus1data

         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance
    189.5721 248.1130 -76.7860 153.5721

    Random effects:
     Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
     site   (Intercept) 4.729e-10 2.175e-05
    Number of obs: 191, groups: site, 6

    Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
    (Intercept)   5.340e+00  2.572e+00   2.076  0.03789 *
    ageJ          1.126e+00  8.316e-01   1.354  0.17583  
    sexM         -3.943e-02  4.562e-01  -0.086  0.93113  
    month.yrFeb-08  -2.259e+01  6.405e+04   0.000  0.99972  
    month.yrFeb-09  -2.201e+01  2.741e+04  -0.001  0.99936  
    month.yrJan-08.516e+00  8.175e-01  -3.078  0.00208 **
    month.yrJan-09 -2.607e+00  8.066e-01  -3.232  0.00123 **
    month.yrJul-08 -1.428e+00  8.571e-01  -1.666  0.09563 .
    month.yrJul-09 -2.795e+00  1.170e+00  -2.389  0.01691 *
    month.yrJun-08 -2.259e+01  3.300e+04  -0.001  0.99945  
    month.yrMar-09 -5.451e-01  6.705e-01  -0.813  0.41622  
    month.yrMar-08 -1.863e+00  7.921e-01  -2.352  0.01869 *
    month.yrMay-09 -6.319e-01  8.956e-01  -0.706  0.48047  
    month.yrMay-08  3.818e-01  1.015e+00   0.376  0.70691  
    month.yrSep-08 2.563e+01  5.806e+05   0.000  0.99996  
    parasiteTRUE -6.329e-03  4.834e-01  -0.013  0.98955  
    SMI          -3.438e-01  1.616e-01  -2.127  0.03342 *
```

And str of my data frame:

```
> str(virus1data)
'data.frame':     191 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ virus1   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ age     : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","J": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ site    : Factor w/ 6 levels “site1”,"site2”,"site3",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 ...
 $ rep : Factor w/ 7 levels "NRF","L","NR",..: 3 7 3 7 1 1 3 1 7 7 ...
 $ month.yr  : Factor w/ 17 levels "Feb-08","Feb-09",..: 4 5 5 5 13 7 14 9 9 9 ...
 $ parasite : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ SMI     : num  14.1 14.8 14.5 13.1 15.3 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:73] 6 12 13 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:73] "1048" "1657" "1866" "2961" ...
```

Without making my actual data available, does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this? I have used this function with a different dataset (same independent variables but a different virus as the response variable, and different records) without problems.

This is the first time I have posted on CV, so I hope that the question is appropriate and that I have provided enough (and the right) information.